# Center aligning multiple lines of text with GD and PHP

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to print multiple lines of text on an image and center align them.

i.e.

This is
A string of text

Right now, I only have the left position for the whole string. Any shortcuts on getting that to work? I think it might have to be a getttfbox on the whole string, then an explode on the line breaks, then center the new text inside that larger ttfbox. That's a pain in the ass...

EDIT: Came up with a solution:

```
    foreach ( $strings as $index => $string ) {
        $parts = explode ( "\n", $string['string'] );
        if ( count ( $parts ) > 1 ) {
            $bounds = imagettfbbox ( intval($string['fontsize']), 0, $font, $string['string'] );
            $width = $bounds[2] - $bounds[0];
            $height = $bounds[3] - $bounds[5];
            $line_height = $height / count ( $parts );

            foreach ( $parts as $index => $part ) {
                $bounds = imagettfbbox ( intval($string['fontsize']), 0, $font, $part );
                $new_width = $bounds[2] - $bounds[0];
                $diff = ( $width - $new_width ) / 2;
                $new_left = $string['left'] + $diff;

                $new_string = $string;
                $new_string['left'] = $new_left;
                $new_string['top'] = $string['top'] + ($index * $line_height);
                $new_string['string'] = $part;
                $new_strings[] = $new_string;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $new_strings )
        $strings = $new_strings;
```

In this case, each $string is an array with some information about how and what to print.
Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question but instead write a new answer (and accept it, if thats the solution that worked for you).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [stil/gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text) class. Disclaimer: I am the author.

```
<?php
use GDText\Box;
use GDText\Color;

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

$textbox = new Box($img);
$textbox->setFontSize(12);
$textbox->setFontFace('arial.ttf');
$textbox->setFontColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
$textbox->setBox(
    50,  // distance from left edge
    50,  // distance from top edge
    200, // textbox width
    100  // textbox height
);

// now we have to align the text horizontally and vertically inside the textbox
$textbox->setTextAlign('center', 'top');
// it accepts multiline text
$textbox->draw("This is\na string of text");
```

Demonstration:

[image: demo]

Comment: I downloaded your code. It works perfectly fine, but probably one of the reasons why not many people is using it, is because it has and downloads a lot of dependencies! your system to align the box is heavier than the client and the server of my plataform together. if you could somehow make it work without the content of /vendor/, more like stand alone method or a function, then you would have something great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that will use the imagettfbbox you mentioned, I can't help with the automatic wordwrapping, but maybe as you suggested, split the string ahead of time.

```
function imagettftext_cr(&$im, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $fontfile, $text)
{
  $bbox = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $fontfile, $text);
  $dx = ($bbox[2]-$bbox[0])/2.0 - ($bbox[2]-$bbox[4])/2.0;
  $dy = ($bbox[3]-$bbox[1])/2.0 + ($bbox[7]-$bbox[1])/2.0;
  $px = $x-$dx;
  $py = $y-$dy;
  return imagettftext($im, $size, $angle, $px, $py, $color, $fontfile, $text);
}
```

Edit: Also found this in the PHP documentation comments...

> Here's a simple function to wrap text going into an image. It'll wrap
>   onto as many lines as it needs to, but $angle has to be zero. The
>   $width parameter is the width of the image.

```
function wrap($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $string, $width)
{
  $ret = "";
  $arr = explode(' ', $string);
  foreach ( $arr as $word )
  {
    $teststring = $ret.' '.$word;
    $testbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $teststring);
    if ( $testbox[2] > $width ){
      $ret.=($ret==""?"":"\n").$word;
    } else {
      $ret.=($ret==""?"":' ').$word;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, it's not center aligned on the image itself, it's center aligned relative to the other lines of text. i.e. the image could be 500px wide, the left of the text could be 100px, the text width could be 150px and have 2 lines, and the text should be center aligned on itself.

Comment: Then I'm going to guess you'll need line by line imagettftext_cr() as you already mentioned. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

search forthe post by "sk89q" on 14-Mar-2008 03:36

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly what I need still. It's cool, I can write the function, I just was hoping someone would have a shortcut

Comment: Yeah I'm not aware of a PHP function that can do this out of the box without iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the excellent [gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text) library.
If you use composer, an example could be this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use GDText\Box;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 18, 64);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);

$box = new Box($im);
$box->setFontFace(__DIR__.'/Pacifico.ttf'); // http://www.dafont.com/pacifico.font
$box->setFontSize(80);
$box->setFontColor([255, 255, 255]);
$box->setTextShadow([0, 0, 0, 50], 0, -2);
$box->setLeading(0.7);
$box->setBox(20, 20, 460, 460);
$box->setTextAlign('center', 'center');
$box->draw("Pacifico");

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my code which works:

function textWithImage($text){  
                $imagePath="/images/fb-share-bg.jpg";
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
                $txtColor = imageColorAllocate($im, 255, 255, 255);  
                $font="/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf";
                $description=$text;
                $in =  wordwrap($description,50,"|",true);
                $st = explode("|",$in);
                //$inStrArr=str_split($description,60);
                $inStrArr=$st;
                $addOnYVal=0;
                foreach($inStrArr as $key=>$value){
                    if($key!=0){
                        $addOnYVal+=40;
                    }
                    list($x, $y) = pc_ImageTTFCenter($im, $value, $font, 20,$addOnYVal);
                    ImageTTFText($im,20,0, $x, $y, $txtColor, $font, $value);
                }

               $newImagename="/uploads/".$img;
               imagejpeg($im, $newImagename,100);

} // Enf of textWithImage function



function pc_ImageTTFCenter($image, $text, $font, $size, $addOnYVal) {
    // find the size of the image
    $xi = ImageSX($image);
    $yi = ImageSY($image);

    // find the size of the text
    $box = ImageTTFBBox($size, $angle, $font, $text);

    $xr = abs(max($box[2], $box[4]));
    $yr = abs(max($box[5], $box[7]));

    // compute centering
    $x = intval(($xi - $xr) / 2);
    $y = intval(($yi + $yr) / 2) +  + $addOnYVal;;

    return array($x, $y);
}

// Calling function
$text = "This is to center alignn the text on image";

textWithImage($text);

//  Output: Image will be saved in the upload folder
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the length of the string (strlen), and an average width of each letter, multiply the strlen result by the average width and then subtract that from your horizontal position.

```
$text="center this";
$h=50;
$h=(strlen($text)*15)-$h;
```

Tell me if it works because I have never tried this

Comment: That's not gonna really cut it for what I'm trying to do. Thanks though.