# What is a workaround for colour coding in wordwrap()

Tags: php

So Minecraft uses section signs (§) for colour coding so for example, light green is §a (a is the color code id for green). An important note to remember is that these are **VISUALLY** ignored in-game. I'm using wordwrap() to make text look centred however these section signs get in the way of that because they're visually not there yet still considered as characters by the function itself.

Here's my attempt: if you take a look, I tried to count the number of occurrences the section sign was found and multiplied it by two for the colour code character. I later then realized that this is inefficient because this affects the entire line of code and not just a specific bit. This basically means that this would make the length of other colour coded lines look odd since they have more or less colour coding in them. I also tried a rather dumb alternative where I'd use constants but I quickly realized that wasn't going to work. Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks in advance.

```
$line = "§r§7This is the §eAuction House§7! In the §eAuction House§7, you can sell and purchase items from other Luriders who have auctioned their items. The §eAuction House §7is a great way to make some cash by simply selling items that other players might be interested in buying."

public static function itemLineOptimizer(string $line, int $width = 40)
{
    $width += substr_count($line, '§') * 2;
    return wordwrap($line, $width, "\n");
}
```

Console Output:

```
string(281) "§r§7This is the §eAuction House§7! In the §eAuction
House§7, you can sell and purchase items from other
Luriders who have auctioned their items. The §eAuction
House §7is a great way to make some cash by simply
selling items that other players might be interested in
buying."
```

In-Game Output:
[In-Game Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgYH3.png)

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and provide an example of the input (`$line` in your example).

Comment: Done. I also included a var dump of the line and an image of what it looks like in-game.

Comment: Using `wordwrap` is not going to give you anything that looks like centered. `wordwrap` is going to simply reduce longer lines and they will line up on the left.

Comment: So, is there an alternative to this? Would maybe removing section signs when the word wrapping happens then adding them back work?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728550/center-aligning-multiple-lines-of-text-with-gd-and-php) appears to have many answers which may help. Search SO for "center text with php" and you will see others that may help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this which I though might be interesting is to take the internal implementation of `wordwrap`, and adapt it to our needs.

So I found the definition in the source, and in particular [the special-case algorithm for handling a single-character line-break character](https://heap.space/xref/php-src/ext/standard/string.c?r=bb1d61a8#914) which is all we need here, and saves us understanding all the other modes.

It works by copying the string, and then walking through it character by character, tracking when it last saw a space, and when it last saw or inserted a newline character. It then over-writes spaces with newline characters in place, without having to touch the rest of the string.

I first translated that literally into PHP (mostly a case of adding `$` in front of each variable, and removing some special type handling macros), giving this:

```
function my_word_wrap($text, $linelength)
{
    $newtext = $text;
    $breakchar = "\n";
    $laststart = $lastspace = 0;
    $string_length = strlen($text);

    for ($current = 0; $current < $string_length; $current++) {
        if ( $text[$current] == $breakchar ) {
            $laststart = $lastspace = $current + 1;
        }
        elseif ( $text[$current] == ' ' ) {
            if ($current - $laststart >= $linelength) {
                $newtext[$current] = $breakchar;
                $laststart = $current + 1;
            }
            $lastspace = $current;
        }
        elseif ($current - $laststart >= $linelength && $laststart != $lastspace) {
            $newtext[$lastspace] = $breakchar;
            $laststart = $lastspace + 1;
        }
    }
    
    return $newtext;
}
```

Two of those `if` statements include this condition which tracks how many characters we've seen since the last line break: `$current - $laststart >= $linelength`. What we could do is subtract from that the number of *invisible* characters we've seen, so they don't contribute to the "width" of lines: `$current - $laststart - $invisibles >= $linelength`.

Next, we need to detect section signs. My immediate guess was to use `$text[$current] == '§'`, but that doesn't work because we're working in byte offsets, and `§` is not a single byte. Assuming UTF-8, it's specifically the pair of bytes which in hexadecimal are `C2 A7`, so we need to test the current *and next* character for that pair: `$text[$current] == "\xC2" && $text[$current+1] == "\xA7"`.

Now we can detect the invisible characters, we can increment our `$invisibles` counter. Since `§` is two bytes, and the following character is *also* invisible, we want to increment the counter by three, and also move the `$current` pointer an extra two steps:

```
elseif ( $text[$current] == "\xC2" && $text[$current+1] == "\xA7" ) {
    $invisibles += 3;
    $current += 2;
}
```

Finally, we need to reset the `$invisibles` counter whenever we insert a newline, or see an existing one - in other words, everywhere we reset `$laststart`.

So, the final result looks like this:

```
function special_word_wrap($text, $linelength)
{
    $newtext = $text;
    $breakchar = "\n";
    $laststart = $lastspace = $invisibles = 0;
    $string_length = strlen($text);

    for ($current = 0; $current < $string_length; $current++) {
        if ( $text[$current] == $breakchar ) {
            $laststart = $lastspace = $current + 1;
            $invisibles = 0;
        }
        elseif ( $text[$current] == ' ' ) {
            if ($current - $laststart - $invisibles >= $linelength) {
                $newtext[$current] = $breakchar;
                $laststart = $current + 1;
                $invisibles = 0;
            }
            $lastspace = $current;
        }
        elseif ( $text[$current] == "\xC2" && $text[$current+1] == "\xA7" ) {
            $invisibles += 3;
            $current += 2;
        }
        elseif ($current - $laststart - $invisibles >= $linelength && $laststart != $lastspace) {
            $newtext[$lastspace] = $breakchar;
            $laststart = $lastspace + 1;
            $invisibles = 0;
        }
    }
    
    return $newtext;
}
```

Here's [a live demo of it in action with your sample input](https://3v4l.org/7lLgR).

Not the most elegant, and probably not the most efficient way to do it, but I enjoyed the exercise, even if it's not what you were hoping for. :)

Comment: Wow! This is astonishing. Thank you so much for your detailed response, it really means a lot that you'd take time out of your day to help me out. Your detailed explanation really helped me understand how it all works now and provided me a much more clarified understanding. I had given this one final attempt before seeing this message and thankfully an alternative method I created worked as well. This is far more advanced than the method I created though so I'll be using this for sure. Was a good experience though.

Answer (score 1):

No where near as efficient as IMSoP's approach, but it is an alternative method I wanted to share. So what I did was I replaced section signs, removed them, wordwrapped, then added them back to their correct places. A bit complicated at first look but it's quite simple. Every line has its details commented.

```
function itemLineOptimizer(string $line, int $width = 40)
{
    $line = str_replace("§", "&", $line); // Since section signs aren't just one-byte, we're going to make our lives easier and replace them with another one-byte symbol, I went with "&"
    $colourCoding = array(); // Straightforward
    $split = str_split($line); // Splitting the line into an array per character
    foreach ($split as $key => $char){ // for every character has a $key (position) and the character itself: $char
        if($char === "&") { // Check if it's a section sign / symbol chosen
            array_push($colourCoding, [$key, $split[$key + 1]]); // add to $colourCoding an element which includes an array consisting of the position of the sign and the colour which the character at the position after
            unset($split[$key]); // remove sign
            unset($split[$key + 1]); // remove colour
        }
    }
    // Now we've removed all colour coding from the line and saved it in $colourCoding
    $bland = wordwrap(implode("", $split), $width, "\n"); // $bland is the now colourless wordwrapped line
    foreach ($colourCoding as $array){ // Lastly we add the section signs back in their positions
        $key = $array[0]; // position
        $colour = $array[1]; // colour
        $lineBreak = substr_count($bland, "§"); // Check for section signs already inside this line: they interfere with future loops since the correct position is different
        $bland = substr_replace($bland, "§".$colour, $key + $lineBreak, 0); // Adding the colour coding back back to its correct position
    }
    return $bland; // Straightforward
}
$line = "§r§7This is the §eAuction House§7! In the §eAuction House§7, you can sell and purchase items from other Luriders who have auctioned their items. The §eAuction House §7is a great way to make some cash by simply selling items that other players might be interested in buying.";
var_dump(wordwrap($line, 40), itemLineOptimizer($line, 40));
```